# DIRTY in RawContacts Android

Tags: android

I'm new in Android and O'm trying to understand how the contacts is working on Android so please bear with me.

I implemented an Observer to observe this URI, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI or ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI.

I am getting notified, and then I query the RawContact like below to get the dirty fields,

```
Cursor cursor = contResv.query(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,
            null, ContactsContract.RawContacts.DIRTY + " = ?", new String[] { "1" }, null);
```

and I do get the accounts that have been changed (Version changed) or deleted. But what I have noticed is that after few seconds I'm getting notified again but this time the dirty rows that I have been notified about in the first time are removed, the DIRTY seems to be cleared after some Sync or something.

How can I guarantee that I will get the dirty rows before it's getting updated?

Because I'm afraid that if my app restarted for some reason and then came back up and then got notified, it won't get the dirty rows as it got cleared during the restart, or any other race condition scenario.

**Edit 1**

After digging for few hours I think I will need to create a raw contact with the same display name. The reason for this is that I think if I do this Android will think that I'm a sync adapter and will make this raw contact entry dirty and it want be cleaned unless I do so.

I'm trying this but it's not working, taken from [here](http://www.c99.org/2010/01/23/writing-an-android-sync-provider-part-2/)

private void addContact(String accountName, String accountType,
        String name, String username) {
    Log.i(Commons.TAG, "Adding contact: " + name);
    ArrayList operationList = new ArrayList();

```
ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation .newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI);
builder.withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null);
builder.withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null);
//builder.withValue(RawContacts.SYNC1, username);
operationList.add(builder.build());


builder = ContentProviderOperation .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
builder.withValueBackReference( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0);
builder.withValue( ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
builder.withValue(  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, name);
operationList.add(builder.build());

try {
    ContentResolver mContentResolver = ContactsUpdateService.this.getContentResolver();

    mContentResolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, operationList);

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(Commons.TAG, "Something went wrong during creation! " + e);
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

This one didn't help also

```
private void addContact(String accountName, String accountType,
        String name, String username) {

    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

    int rawContactInsertIndex = ops.size();
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType)
            .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName).build());

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
            .newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
            .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
            .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, "09876543")

            .build());


    try {
        getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```